# units of magnetizing force

Tags: electromagnetism

In electromagnetic field theory, we talk about "magnetizing force". Units of magnetizing force is A/m (Amperes per meter). It's obvious that units of force is Newton. So, is amperes per meter equal to Newton?

Answer (score 2):

Amps per metre is *Magnetic field* or *Magnetic field strength*. Amps are actually the current flow x number of turns resulting in the more preferable: -

H = (ampere turns) per metre

Sometimes H is described as *magnetizing force*.

See this table linked in the deleted answer that I sneakily copied: -

[image]

*Magneto motive force* is ampere turns and neither have the units of newton.